# Python Scapy a Recursive DNS Query

Tags: python, dns, scapy

I am trying to create a recursive DNS query packet using Python scapy to showcase the amplification vulnerability on open dns resolver. Below is the packet:

```
p = IP(src=srcIP,dst=destIP) / UDP(sport=53,dport=53) / DNS(qd=DNSQR(qname="isc.org", qtype="ANY"))
send(p)
```

However, the reply does not shows any amplification. In fact the response is lesser in size than the packet sent.

Is my packet structure correct above? How do I make it a recursive query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your packet is correct and should work. I have just checked with Google's public DNS server 8.8.8.8, the packet I send is 53 bytes long, the answer I get is 107.

The "recursion desired" bit is activated in Scapy by default (you can enter `DNS().rd` and check it returns 1), so there's nothing more you need to do here.

The only weird thing I can see is that you are using the source port 53, and some firewalls may filter packets with source ports < 1024. You can try with a random source port see if it works better.